# Text nodes cannot appear as a child of <tbody>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

My code is really simple and I checked everything but this is getting this error repeatedly. Please suggest to me what can i change. I tried using  but that dint work.I even checked other answers but they dint work.

```
 import React from "react";
import { Button, Table } from "react-bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Employees from "./Employees";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {Employees && Employees > 0 ? Employees.map((item) => {
                  return (
                    <tr key={item.id}>
                      <td>{item.name}</td>
                      <td>{item.age}</td>
                    </tr>
                  );
                })
              : "No data available"}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: `"No data available"` needs to be in a tr and td

Answer (score 0):

If there is no data your table would look like

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    No data available
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It needs to have a `<tr>` and a `<td>`